# Mac - Holding Option at Start Up and Choosing EFI Boot - "System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults."

Tags: boot, dual-boot, mac, grub-efi, boot-order

I set up my old 2012 Macbook Pro to have dual boot with MacOS and Ubuntu 20.04. I installed Grub Customizer so that when I turn the laptop on, it always defaults to boot Ubuntu. However, when I hold `option` after pressing power to turn it on and I select "EFI Boot" (Ubuntu), a terminal-esque screen pops up saying some stuff about not having ER state objects for different volumes, and, more importantly:

> System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults.

This doesn't seem to be problematic in any way, as this screen goes away pretty quickly and Ubuntu boots up fine. I am just curious why this happens and if there is any way to change this behavior.

Comment: I'm having this EXACT same issue and would love to solve it but in the meantime would like to just start up my macos.  Can I ask how you're doing that?

Comment: Yeah of course. Are you certain that you have a dual boot and not just Ubuntu? If you are sure you still have MacOS, you should just be able to hold `option` when you turn your computer on, and you'll be able to choose between your Ubuntu EFI and MacOS.

Comment: thanks so much for responding, sorry I forgot to come back to askubuntu to see your answer.  I didn't see the other boot options when holding `option`, I think I may have missed a step somewhere.  I ended up messing with my drive partitions and screw those up and eventually wiped my whole computer

Comment: in the end I actually followed a youtube guide and was able to do it correctly the second time

Comment: Good, I am glad!